# D3.js: Why are my legend tick marks' text disappearing?

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, legend

I have a linear-gradient legend for my map. The x-axis values are calculated based on the minimum 
and maximum values from the underlying data.  I adapted this legend from this website:
https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2016/05/smooth-color-legend-d3-svg-gradient.html

The legend shows up when user selects a "field condition" from the dropdownlist.  However, when
user selects a "state" from a dropdownlist, all the tick marks' text disappear.  Same thing when user
selects a "county" from another dropdownlist.  I haven't had luck trying to figure this out.

I'm calculating the tick mark values (shows as text) as follows:

```
var dataRange = getDataRange();
var min = parseFloat(dataRange[0].toFixed(3));
var max = parseFloat(dataRange[1].toFixed(3));
var legendW = 160, legendH = 20;

//create tick marks
var legendX = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([min, max])
    .range([0, legendW]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(legendX);

d3.select("#svgLegend")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", legendW)
    .attr("height", legendH * 2)
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "g-legend")
    .attr("transform", "translate(2," + legendH + ")")   //margin.left; height/2
    .call(axis);
```

For  working example, please see:  http://realtimeceap.brc.tamus.edu

Answer (score 0):

I just glanced at the code on the page you referenced the working example at and think I figured out the issue.

Here's the line that taking out the ticks from the legend `SVG`:

```
d3.selectAll("text").remove();
```

which is a part of the `onChange` function for `$("#stateSelect")`.

**Line number: 279 to be more specific (in index.html file)**

I think you want to take out all the texts from the **mainSVG** i.e. with the `id: svgMap2`.

Changing the above selection will fix the issue. (for eg. if you have a class for the texts to be removed, use `d3.selectAll('text.<classname>')`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it's "disappearing". The Web is a stateless medium. So, every time I changed selection from the dropdownlist, the svg refreshes and losses its current state. So I needed to re-create my legend for the state and county dropdownlists. But also, for the county dropdownlist, since there is a Zoom function, it meant that everytime I zoom to another county, I loss my map state again. So I moved the recreate legend function into the zoomedIn method (that is, AFTER the zoom state). It works now.